# foreign keys without on delete cascade

Tags: sql, cascading-deletes

I have two tables:

```
Challenge:

challengeID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
...
```

And

```
UserChallenge:

ID INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY
challengeID INTEGER NOT NULL
...
FOREIGN KEY(challengeid) REFERENCES challenge(challengeID)
```

If I have one row on challenge table, with challengeID = 1, and one row on UserChallenge table with challengeID = 1.

What would happen with UserChallenge table if I delete the row from the Challenge? May I use `ON DELETE CASCADE` with `UserChallenge.challengeID`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a test...

If you delete the row from Challenge, the constraint on challengeID in UserChallenge gets violated. You have to delete all referencing records in this table as well, or update these records using another (correct) value or use a NULL. You could also use ON DELETE CASCADE when you want to delete the referencing records.

Answer (score 1):

With `DELETE CASCADE` removing a record from `Challenge` causes all child records in `UserChallenge` to be deleted.

Maybe this helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#Referential_Actions